# Challanges in transforming data with tXMLMap Talend

Tags: schema, etl, talend

I'am new to talend and have been trying to understand tXMLMap of talend. I have  a couple of questions regarding it which I have difficulty in understanding.

1. Importing schema via xsd: I have seen that the tXMLMap is able to generate the input and output flow when schema is uploaded. But the problem I founded with that schema is that the schema cannot be uploaded as xsd. And the currently uploaded schema is in xml extension containing some talend specific tags. Is there anyway to do this with normal xsd. I saw a method of building schema by uploading to the File xml on the repository but it wasnt doing any good in solving this problem because it is just placed there and not being able to import to tXMLMap. Is there anyway to solve this?
2. Lets say the input of tXMLMap contains an array in one of it sub branch. Can I map this array to different vairables in the output flow? Can that level of complication be handled by the tXMLMap?
3. What is the exact need of aggregate and loop in tXMLMap?

Answer (score 1):

1)In the Metadata section of the repository, you will be able to create metadata (schema) linked to your input xml/xsd file. (careful : you'll need a metadata to READ data, and one to WRITE data)
Then when you have created metadata, you can use it in tXMLMap (just right-click on root Element (type must be document) in your tXMLMap and select "import from Repository".

2)You have to use the "loop element" in tXMLMap and place it on your array : this way you will be able to extract all data from your array and send it to your output flow.

3. Loop element is crucial in tXMLMap : this will allow you to correctly extract data from your xml input flow.
   If you have multiple parallel loop like this :

You'll need 2 loop element (one for elementA , one for element B ) and 2 output flows in order to read all data.

Comment: when I mean array the array could be something like this ["item1", "item2", "item3" ] so basically it could be variable in length. If it is variable in length can it be able to map to an object array like this {"key1":"item1", "key2":"item2", "key3":"item3" }.

Comment: apart from loop there is something called aggregate in the tXMLMap. What is it significance of it.